# Eject unreadable DVD from slot-in drive

Tags: disk, eject

I have an external USB DVD *slot-in* drive. It does not have any eject buttons. I inserted a DVD which can't be read (too many scratches I guess). Now I do not know how I can eject the disc - as there is no media yet recognized, I do not get a drive mapping, so `eject` does not do much.

dmesg output:

```
[80954.473663] usb 2-1.3.2.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[80954.571274] scsi1183 : usb-storage 2-1.3.2.1:1.0
[80955.570242] scsi 1183:0:0:0: CD-ROM            MATSHITA DVD-R   UJ-898   HC10 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[80955.583425] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[80955.583774] sr 1183:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[80955.584018] sr 1183:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
```

sudo cdrecord -eject sg3

```
wodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

and --devices and -scanbus do not show the drive.

Answer (score 2):

The hard way (if nothing else works): There should be a little hole in front of the drive. Just big enough for a needle. If you take a paperclip and unfold it you can press it in that hole - but keep straight. And the DVD should pop out.

Comment: It's slot loaded, so that may not work.

Answer (score 1):

While it probably does not amount to more than sg3, you could try `cdrecord -eject /dev/sr0`, maybe also `eject -r /dev/sr0` and `eject -s /dev/sg3`.

If that fails, and your drive has a pin hole, get a long pin (traditionally a clipboard pin folded open one or two bends) and push.

If your drive has a physical eject button, you could try `eject -i off /dev/sr0` and press the button.

If all these fail, it is possible that you have more control over the drive during BIOS boot up procedure.

Answer (score 0):

No need to type too much.
Simply one command in terminal :

> eject

Thats all. When this does not work. Plug out usb-dvd-drive and
then type commands with enter each :

> reset

> eject